# How does Spring Data (JPA) relate to JPA persistence providers?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to wrap my head around JPA and have learned quite a bit. JPA is a java specification and providers implement this spec. I Understand that part.

What I don't understand is how Spring Data comes into the picture. Is Spring Data also a provider like Hibernate or OpenJPA? If not, what is it? How does Spring Data "make things easier"?

Comment: you are asking about Spring Data JPA?

Comment: yea this spring data jpa: http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-jpa/

Comment: Spring Data JPA automatically implements common JPA data access methods for you based only on the Entity objects. It is based on Grails Object Relational Mapping (GORM) and uses the same conventions. The names of the automatically created methods also describe what the method will return. If you have an object Foo with property bar and want to find all Foos of a certain bar, you just call the automatically created method Foo.findByBar(). Let's say Foo has a dateCreated property and you want to find all Foos created in a certain timeframe, use Foo.findByDateCreatedBetween(firstDate, secondDate)

Comment: vance, so it is a provider? I don't need to use OPENJPA or Hibernate? Or does it still require a provider while implementing those methods?

Answer (score 12):

The Spring Data project in general is an umbrella project with the following mission statement:

> … provide a familiar and consistent Spring-based programming model while retaining store-specific features and capabilities.

So we approach the persistence space in general not only relational data access through JPA. The important piece here is two fold:

1. Programming model instead of generic API
2. Support for store specific features

As the data access space is so diverse these days, trying to approach all of the stores with a single unifying API is doomed to fail. You'd end up with a least common denominator that hides away the store specific parts - in times where you selectively choose a particular store *because* of it's specifics. Abstracting those away totally subverts this. Especially trying to use JPA is wrong in our opinion as it's deeply tied to relational concepts (`@Table`, joins, transactions) by definition.

Still, you don't want to work with completely different APIs, don't wanna be lost in store differences if you work with multiple ones or switch from one project to another. Spring has traditionally helped in that regard by embracing a consistent programming model, that features abstractions that work the same way but are still specific to a particular technology. For example, JDBC and JMS are completely different technologies. Spring offers both a `JdbcTemplate` as well as a `JmsTemplate` that cover the same responsibilities (resource management and exception translation) and lower the learning curve when moving from working with JDBC to JMS or vice versa.

Spring Data picks up on that by exposing store-specific functionality through abstractions that Spring developers know. I already mentioned the template, but that also includes general configuration mechanisms (XML namespaces, using DI and AOP etc.).

## Repositories

The very top layer of this programming model is the repository abstraction. In its core, it significantly simplifies the development of data access layers by letting you avoid to write more implementation code than strictly necessary. It provides CRUD functionality out of the box, pagination as well as declarative query methods.

Assume a `Customer` domain class. Enabling persistence for it is just a matter of declaring a repository interface like this:

```
interface CustomerRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Customer, Long> {

  List<Customer> findByLastnameContaining(String lastname);
}
```

Now it's a matter of configuration (and domain class mapping) to be able to create an instance of this interface and use it from a client. `PagingAndSortingRepository` includes basic CRUD functionality as well as stuff like `Page<Customer> findAll(Pageable pageable)` (so page-by-page access). As you can see, we also support a query derivation mechanism to avoid needing to write any implementation code for simply queries. For more complex ones, we allow the manual declaration (e.g. using `@Query` on the method) or even the manual implementation if necessary.

A neat side-effect here is, that by a flip-switch in the configuration you could use the same repository interface to persist `Customer` instances into a MongoDB. That doesn't mean we recommend to blindly move from one store to another as the stores usually require the data model to be adapted to work efficiently. However it allows developers to quickly switch between projects working with different stores as the repositories just work the same way (implementing the programming model over common API approach).

## JPA specifics

Spring Data JPA is actually a thin layer implementing the repository abstraction plus a few other bells and whistles. So we're not replacing persistence providers but actually leverage them through the API, even mitigating some of the quirks and differences between individual JPA providers.

Comment: Detailed response but it doesn't answer the fundamental question "Is Spring Data JPA a provider, or is it a layer above JPA which still requires a provider (OpenJPA, Hibernate, EclipseLink, etc) underneath?"

Comment: This answer is too long, not specific.

Answer (score 2):

Think of Spring Data as a way to support JPA and many other persistence models in a manner that is transparent to your own code. Spring Data makes it easier for you to manipulate more types of data source systems in a unified interface. Without Spring Data, you would need to introduce more adapters in your code, each time you would have to deal with extra logic.

Answer (score 2):

`spring-data JPA` is not a JPA provider. It is a library / framework that adds an **extra layer of abstraction** on the top of our JPA provider(Hibernate/TopLink). If you are using Spring Data in your project, you are not going to write most of the low level data access operations like writing SQL query, DAO classes etc.

But you must have a JPA-Provider (Hibernate, Toplink etc) to implement spring-data-jpa.